# Android Studio и Eclipse экспортит битый apk, что делать?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

Программирую под андроид, и раньше все было нормально.

Скачал SDK и к нему Eclipse и погнал, все нормально. И вот буквально пару дней назад я windows (7 x32) переустановил, поставил SDK, скачал все api (SDK Platform)... При сборке apk ошибок не пишет, а сам apk выходит битый (Синтаксическая ошибка при анализе пакета). Я разархивировал apk и в нем нет папок "bin" и "libs". При сборке их не создает... Я удалил SDK и Eclipse и поставил Android Studio, а при его установке указал и SDK поставить. Он все сделал, и я еще скачал через SDK Manager нужные версии api(SDK Platform), но и он при сборке мне выдает битый apk, как и Eclipse. Потом я еще скачал все "ARM EABI v7a", но и тут ничего не помогло. Хотя раньше только SDK Platforms качал в SDK Manager.

Comment: > в нем нет папок "bin" и "libs"

А с чего вы взяли, что они должны там быть?    
Вы на разных устройствах пробовали? Может, это проблема устройства?

Comment: Пробовал на Nokia X(android 4.1) и Asus tf300t(android 4.4), везде ошибка.

"А с чего вы взяли, что они должны там быть?" Раньше, когда все работало, они там были.

Comment: Можно полный текст ошибки и скрин установленных API из менеджера?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, папки может и не быть. Если вы не добавляли файлы в *lib*, то и папки в собранном *.apk* не будет.

Во-вторых, возможно, вы поставили слишком высокий API.